# Entity Framework Core - Append conditional where clause

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I am trying to add an additional `where` clause if a specific `queryParameter` is passed in through the url, but it doesn't seem to be working. Before I result to doing raw sql, I want to first figure out if I'm doing it correct (documentation seems to be minimal for this as I can't find anything)

**Code minimized for brevity**

```
public IActionResult RetrieveAll([FromQuery] string orderByDate, [FromQuery] string taskStatus)
{
    try
    {
        var taskQuery = (from t in _context.Tasks select t);
        switch(taskStatus)
        {
            case "completed":
                taskQuery.Where(t => t.IsCompleted == true);
                break;
            case "notcompleted":
                taskQuery.Where(t => t.IsCompleted == false);
                break;
        }

        var tasks = taskQuery.ToList();
        return Ok(tasks);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

}
```

I was thinking that simply appending the `Where` clause would do it. The code executes the proper code path, but It still comes back with all results.

Comment: Whats wrong here?

Comment: The return contains values that doesn't match the query. (ie: if I query for IsCompleted = true, I get both true and false values). I take it from your question, the code is correct and the issue is somewhere else...

Comment: maybe I need to do `taskQuery = taskQuery.Where(...)`. Trying that now.

Comment: Have debugged it which `case` is executing?

Comment: Yea, everything is doing what it's supposed to. It turns out the issue was what I just stated (I need to set the `taskQuery` when I append the clause, not just append it and not update the original query)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188716/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-mwilson).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You define the base query here:

```
var taskQuery = (from t in _context.Tasks select t);
```

Later, you call the `.Where(...)` extension method on the query in order to further filter the query:

```
 case "completed":
        taskQuery.Where(t => t.IsCompleted == true);
        break;
```

However, `.Where(...)` doesn't replace the `IQueryable`, it returns a *new* `IQueryable`.  As you noted in the comments, you need to replace the query with the new query so that your call to `.ToList()` returns the expected results later.

Like this:

```
taskQuery = taskQuery.Where(t => t.IsCompleted == true);
```

That's a pretty common pattern for "building up" queries in Entity Framework, so you're definitely on the right track!

Comment: What about using select after conditions? Like `taskQuery.Select(t => new { t.id, t.name});`